# How can I compare the 2 lists and replace it?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, class, methods

(Hello community, I am learning programming. Improvements and tips after solution are welcome). I am making a CRUD class to record and manipulate basic user data. The actualizar_datos_usuario method is in charge of updating this data. I need to compare 2 lists. listaUsers is where the user data is stored and listaUsers2 is the new list that stores the data, the auxiliary of listUsers to replace the values. I am trying to compare the 2 lists. I want to make changes that only affect the user information and not the Cedula and just in case Cedula when updating validate that it is not assigned by another user.

```
def actualizar_datos_usuario(self):
        clear()
            #Buscamos y mostramos los datos del usuario en primer lugar
        ced = int(input("Ingrese la cédula del usuario: "))
        user_found = False
        for i in self.listaUsers:
            if i["Cedula"] == ced:
                for key, value in i.items():
                    print(f"{key}: {value}")
                    user_found = True
                break       
        if not user_found:
            print("Cédula no registrada.")
        print("\n\n[Actualizar usuario al sistema]\n")

        #Luego de mostrar los datos, ingresamos los datos a modificar
        for i in range(1):
            #Usamos diccionario para establecer datos especificos y orden del usuario
            usr_prototype = {
                'Nombres'  : '',
                'Apellidos': '',
                'Edad'     : '',
                'Cedula'   : ''
            }
            usr_prototype['Nombres'] = input("Nombres: ")
            usr_prototype['Apellidos'] = input("Apellidos: ")
            usr_prototype['Edad'] = int(input("Edad: "))
            usr_prototype['Cedula'] = int(input("Cédula: "))
            #Antes de proceder a guardar el usuario se validará la cédula. Es una llave única de cada usuario
            self.listaUsers2.append(usr_prototype)
            result = any(i == j for i, j in zip(self.listaUsers, self.listaUsers2))
            
            if result:
                modificar_listas = modificar_items(self.listaUsers, self.listaUsers[:], self.listaUsers2)
                self.mostrar_datos_usuario(usr_prototype["Cedula"])
            else:
                print("no")
```

```
def mostrar_datos_usuario(self, ced):
        user_found = False
        for i in self.listaUsers:
            if i["Cedula"] == ced:
                for key, value in i.items():
                    print(f"{key}: {value}")
                    user_found = True
                break
```

```
def modificar_items(lista, valores_actuales=[], valores_nuevos=[]):
       for i, sublista, in enumerate(lista):
           if all(item_act is None or item_act == item_list
                  for item_list, item_act in zip(sublista, valores_actuales)):
               for j, item_nuevo in enumerate(valores_nuevos):
                   if item_nuevo is not None:
                       lista[i][j] = item_nuevo
```

Comment: `print("\n\n[Actualizar usuario al sistema]\n")` is not indented properly.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Is there a specific problem with your code you need help with? If so, please indicate it clearly. If you're just looking for feedback/code review, this is not the right site, you should ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: There's no point to `for i in range(1):` That just iterates one time, which is the same as no iteration at all.

Comment: Why are you comparing lists? If the user is found in the first loop, you should modify that user. If they're not found, ask for the other fields and append the new user to the list. You don't need two user lists.

Comment: I think I understand. Yes, the user should be found in the first loop (although not this one, I just realized that the data stream is still running). The question is that, I want to modify the data as you say but I don't know how you would do it. I understand if there is a lot of junk code. I try what I can :)

Answer (score 0):

Done. Actually creating another list was unnecessary. After "if not user_found". I added an else to replace the data. I added a for loop iterating over theUser list, of course. There is no point in instantiating the list by calling with all its data. Since the variable ced must already be stored, otherwise the code block would never execute. And a couple of conditions. I had a lot of trouble until I had to set Cedula first (Cedula is an identity document. A unique value for the user). So it had to be modifiable the same value or another one that is not registered in the system.

```
    else:
        print("\n\n[Actualizar usuario al sistema]\n")
        #Luego de mostrar los datos, ingresamos los datos a modificar
        for i in self.listaUsers:
            if i["Cedula"] == ced:
                ced_aux = int(input("Debe ingresar la cédula\nActualizar/Misma: "))
                if ced_aux != ced and self.validarID_Usuario(ced_aux):
                    pass
                if ced_aux:
                    print("La cédula ya esta registrada por otro usuario")
                else:
                    i['Nombres'] = input("Nombres: ")
                    i['Apellidos'] = input("Apellidos: ")
                    i['Edad'] = int(input("Edad: "))
                    i['Cedula'] = ced_aux
                    print("¡Usuario Actualizadox!")
                break
        else:
            print("Cédula no registrada en el sistema.")
```